# Variable is protected when using friend function

Tags: c++, function, private, protected

I've had to make a program which shows the `name`, `surname` and the `year` of birth of a child. Everything is working well, excepting the `friend` function, which have to access the `private`/`protected` variable `birth_year` and to show `0` if his `birth_year` is bigger than `2007`, else to show `1`.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class child{
protected:

    char name[20],surname[20];
    int birth_year;
public:

    child(char*,char*,int);
    getyear();
    show();
    friend void itsolder();
};

child::child(char* n, char* p, int a)
{

    strcpy(name,n);
    strcpy(surname,p);
    birth_year=a;
}

child::getyear()
{

    return birth_year;
}

child::show()
{

    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Surname: " << surname << endl;
    cout << "Year of birth: " << birth_year << endl;
}

void itsolder(child&year)
{

    if (year.birth_year>2007)
        cout << "0" << endl;
    else
        cout << "1" << endl;
}

int main()
{

    child c1("Richard", "John", 1997);
    c1.show();
    cout << c1.getyear() << endl;
    itsolder(c1.birth_year)
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

1. `int child::birth_year` is `protected`;
2. "within this context" - is where I've put the condition in the `friend` function and where I called it, into `main()`;
3. invalid initialization of reference of type `child&` from expression of type `int`

Comment: `child::getyear()` is an error (if this is meant to introduce a function body, there must be a return type specified beforehand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A declaration of `friend void itsolder();` doesn't match a definition of

```
void itsolder(child&year)
{
    if (year.birth_year>2007)
        cout << "0" << endl;
    else
        cout << "1" << endl;
}
```

Change it to `friend void itsolder(child&);` and pass the parameter accordingly:

```
itsolder(c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @StoryTeller has written in his answer, but in addition to that your program is invalid since `C++11`. String literals are of type `const char[n]`, which decays into `const char*`, but by default compilers like `g++` and `clang++` accepts this code for backward compatibility reasons. If you use `-pedantic-errors` command line option, you will get compiler error.

Addition to this, return type of `getyear()` and `show()` member function is missing. You must explicitly specify return type of each and every function.

See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79388046588069da). 
Observe the warnings given by the compiler:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra   main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:53:37: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

     child c1("Richard", "John", 1997);

                                     ^

main.cpp:53:37: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

So your correct code should be like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f42335334a1132b).